# binding data with ui-jq slider in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a page where users can rate their performance in different categories. I am using the ui-jq slider for angular and i want to bind the selected value to a model in $scope.

```
<div ng-repeat="competence in screening_has_skillset.skillset.competences">
    <div class="col-sm-12 m-b-md">
        <p class="h3">{{competence.competence.name}}</p>
        {{competence.competence.level}}
        <input id="slider"
               ui-jq="slider"
               ui-options="{
                  min: 0,
                  max: 10,
                  step: 1,
                  value: {{competence.competence.level || val }}
               }"
               ng-model="competence.competence.level"
               class="slider slider-horizontal form-control" type="text">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and write an attribute directive which is named as **ng-slider-model** for value binding.

```js
 .directive('ngSliderModel', ['$parse', function($parse) {
   return {
     scope: {
       ngSliderModel: '=',
       uiOptions: '='
     },
     restrict: 'A',
     required: ['ngSliderModel'],
     link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
       // check there is uiOption or not 
       var options = ('uiOptions' in attrs) ? scope.uiOptions : {};
       // get the value of ngSlider Model 
       var val = scope.ngSliderModel;
       // if value is  range   [15,25]   then return values for uiOptions propertyName  else value for singles   
       var propName = (angular.isArray(val)) ? 'values' : 'value';
       /* if you  want to slide when the scope value changed not from slider... 
        watch the ngSliderModel attribute 
       */
       scope.$watch('ngSliderModel', function(newValue) {

         element.slider(propName, newValue);
       });
       // set value for options 
       options[propName] = val;
       // binding slide event 
       element.bind('slide', function() {
         // Read the current value 
         var value = element.slider('option', propName);

         scope.$apply(function() {
           // Apply the value to scope 
           scope.ngSliderModel = value;
         });
       });
     }
   };
 }]);;
```

Comment: This answer is a lot more informative if you add a description of what you've done and how it answers the users question

Comment: i am trying to do  but i have problem with 4 space intent  .. this is my first answer.. pre code  `` i use but can not update it ...

Answer (score 0):

```
 <input id="slider" ui-jq="slider" value="val" ui-options="{
          min: 1,
          max: 100,
          step: 1,
          value: val
        }" ui-event="{slideStop: 'updateModel($event)'}" class="slider slider-horizontal form-control" type="text">
```

value = "val"
do this. in your html element input set the value. where val is scope variable

Comment: <input id="slider" ui-jq="slider" value="val" ui-options="{
              min: 1,
              max: 100,
              step: 1,
              value: val
            }" ui-event="{slideStop: 'updateModel($event)'}" class="slider slider-horizontal form-control" type="text"> {{val}}


do this. in your html element input set the value.

Comment: Please consider using "edit" to update the answer and delete this comment